# How to update UI from within a Timer on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a timer that I use to check a web address every 11 seconds. I use ASIHTTPRequest to set a delegate which reports the response form the web server. If I get the response I'm looking for, I want to update the UI. Unfortunately this doesn't work, I suspect because I am not updating the UI from the UI thread.

Code to start and process timer:

```
- (void)startTimer {
BOOL timerStarted = false;
BOOL running = false;
BOOL readyToProcess = false;

if(!timerStarted){
    running = true;
    timerStarted = true;
    readyToProcess = true;
    autosaveTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11
                                                      target:self
                                              selector:@selector(processWebCheckTimer:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES] retain];
}
```

}

```
- (void)processWebCheckTimer:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    if ([VariableStore sharedInstance].success < 1) { //conversion not done, check again
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"WEBSERVERURLHERE"];
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setPostValue:oc_request forKey:@"queue"];
        [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request startAsynchronous];
    }
}
```

Check response and update UI:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    if ([responseString rangeOfString:@"uccessfully converted"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(threadStopAnimatingTwo:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; //DOESNT WORK
        [autosaveTimer invalidate];

    }   

}
```

Function to Update UI:

```
- (void) threadStopAnimatingTwo:(id)data {
    NSLog(@"stop animating two");
    [loadingTwo stopAnimating];
    [labelTwo setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a timer that repeats and then invalidating it?

Comment: I only invalidate once I get what I'm checking for, otherwise it checks again in 11 seconds. Either way, it doesn't matter because I know `threadStopAnimatingTwo` runs, it just doesn't run in the correct thread because the UI doesn't change.

Comment: Checking which thread a line of code is run on is easy. 1) Put a breakpoint on the line in question. 2) Run until breakpoint. 3) From the menu select View->Navigators->Show Debug Navigator there you will be able to see your call stack separated by thread.

Comment: The code to update the UI is being run in Thread 1 according to the Debug Navigator. Any idea why the UI doesn't actually update? If I call the same function from `ViewDidLoad` it works, so I know there's nothing wrong with the UI updating code.

Comment: In threadDtopAnimatingTwo, try NSLog(@"loadingTwo = %@",loadingTwo) This will check to see what your pointer is pointed at.

Comment: Well, this is obviously the issue: `loadingTwo = (null)`. In my .h, I have `@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *labelTwo;` and I synthesize it in the .m. Why is it null when accessed within the timer/delegate? How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to be clear is threadStopAnimatingTwo a method in your viewController?

Comment: Yes, all this code is in the same view controller.

Comment: Posted educated guess answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was creating a new instance of my View controller when I didn't need to. Because I created a new instance of the view controller, `[self.loadingTwo]` referred to a `null` UI component.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the UI by using the properties not the instance variables.

For Example:

```
- (void) threadStopAnimatingTwo:(id)data {
    NSLog(@"stop animating two");
    [self.loadingTwo stopAnimating];
    [self.labelTwo setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
}
```

Comment: `self.loadingTwo` comes up as `null` as well. Is it possible `self` is not what it normally is since it is inside of an ASIHTTPRequest response delegate?

Comment: No, but your wording concerns me. It is my understanding that threadStopAnimatingTwo is a method of your view controller class and is simply being called by the asihttpRequest as a delegate method. If that is correct then the only remaining explanation can be that something sets your UI components to nil after the viewDidLoad method. Just for reference no UI component should be set to nil anywhere before viewDidUnload. Try searching for anywhere any UI component is set to nil.

Comment: For whatever reason, any UI component accessed from the ASIHTTP delegate methods is null. I "solved" the problem by saving the UI components I need to use in the delegate to globals in viewDidLoad.

Comment: The self.properties are global. Something is still wrong, which I know you know based on the "solved" quotes. Have you tried calling that function anywhere else besides viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

//can you add log ? print?

```
NSLog(@"execute performSelectorOnMainThread");
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(threadStopAnimatingTwo:) 
                       withObject:nil 
                    waitUntilDone:YES]; //DOESNT WORK
```

Comment: Yes, If I add that log statement, it does show up in the output. Same for the `threadStopAnimatingTwo` function. I know both functions are run, but the UI never gets updated.